# Triggers on DuplicateRecordSet and DuplicateRecordItem

Tags: trigger, duplicate-management

I'm trying to write an after insert trigger on DuplicateRecordSet and DuplicateRecordItem but the triggers never fire.
Does anyone know if it is supported and how it can be done?

Comment: As i understand you want write a trigger which will prevent creating duplicate records ?

Comment: @Prabhat [Managing Duplicate Records in Salesforce](https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_quality_duplicate_prevention.pdf)

Comment: @Prabhat not really, I want to perform some action when a DuplicateRecordSet and DuplicateRecordItem are being created or updated

Comment: @Dedo I realize you may have already worked around this issue, but it doesn't seem like the triggers appear in the debug log at all. However, try doing a DML operation or something - like create a test account in the trigger. That seems to be working for me! (But this is indeed very strange.)

Comment: Were you able to sort this out? I stumbled upon the same issue

Answer (score 1):

@Dedo The triggers are supported! They are run by the Automated Process user and not your current running user, so you need to take a few extra steps when debugging this process to see that it is running.

1. Navigate to Setup -> Debug Logs
2. Click "New"
3. For "Traced Entity Type", choose "Automated Process"

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: @BorisBachovski Me? Yes. Otherwise I wouldn't have put it as the answer. I have to debug these triggers fairly often.

Comment: I just stuck a debug log statement in the trigger, created a bunch of duplicate records which match the rule (Duplicate Record Items created), even updated, yet I can't see anything in the logs. The trigger is not even firing at all...

Comment: And you have debug logging enabled on the Automated Process user? Can you try inserting a fake test record or updating a record in the trigger? The record should be inserted/updated and show the Automated Process user as the Last Modified By. It's late here, but if you're still having issues I can try to make my answer more detailed with screenshots tomorrow.

Comment: It's interesting, I wrote some invalid code and I can see the error logs for duplicate items are showing the error in my handler class. Though, I can't see the actual debug log for the Automated Process (yes I'm monitoring logs for that entity)....

Comment: Ok it seems like someone had changed the logging levels. Now I can see the transaction logs, however, only on insert. Is Update supported?

Comment: @BorisBachovski Sorry, I just saw this. I would assume that update is supported, though I believe my code only runs on insert of new duplicate record items. If you're still having trouble we could move this discussion into a chat though.

Comment: My bad, on update only the record updates but not the duplicate record item, therefore the trigger won't fire. All good!